# How do I use `serde_json_core` to deserialise an array without allocations?

Tags: rust, serde

How can I deserialise JSON `{"arr":[1,2,3,4]}` without performing a heap allocation using [`serde_json_core`](https://docs.rs/serde-json-core/0.4.0/serde_json_core/index.html) or similar? It performs one allocation currently. I see `serde_json_core` uses the `heapless` crate but I am unsure exactly how to make them work together.

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    arr: Vec<u64>,
}

fn main() {
    let j = r#"{"arr":[1,2,3,4]}"#;

    let r: serde_json_core::de::Result<(MyStruct, usize)> = serde_json_core::from_str(j);
    let (out, _) = r.unwrap();

    println!("First value: {}.",  out.arr[0]);
}
```

I am using `serde_json_core = 0.4.0`.

Comment: Do you know the exact size of the array in advance? If so, you can simply deserialize to a fixed-sized array `[u64; N]`. If not, you need to decide on a maximum possible array size you want to be able to deserialize. You need to preallocate everything on the stack, so you can't support arbitrary sizes. Using `Vec` is not an option, since it will allocate if it contains any elements.

Comment: Thanks, I know the array must be less than or equal to 10 elements long. Unfortunately if I do `[u64; 10]` I get `'called 'Result::unwrap()' on an 'Err' value: CustomError'`. I need the array size to be exactly 4 (`[u64; 4]`) to work.

Comment: For a variable size, you can't use a fixed-sized array. You need to use some stack-allocated vector-like data structure, e.g. `heapless::Vec`. You should be able to add `use serde_json_core::heapless::Vec;` to your code, and then add `10` as second template parameter to the `Vec` inside `MyStruct`.

Comment: That was my initial hope when using `serde_json_core` however the `Deserialize` trait is not implemented for all the varieties of `heapless::Vec`: `the trait 'Deserialize<'_>' is not implemented for 'serde_json_core::heapless
::Vec<u64, 4_usize>`. I could implement the `Deserialize` myself for the `Vec` capacity I want but was hoping I didn't have to do that.

Comment: You need to enable the `serde` feature for `heapless` to get the impl.

Comment: It is enabled (`serde-json-core = { version = "0.4.0", features = ["heapless", "std"] }`. I don't see any `heapless::Vec` implementation in the `serde_json_core` code though.

Comment: The serde-json-core crate re-exports heapless, so you can use it with `use serde_json_core::heapless::Vec;`, as mentioned above. To enable a feature for the heapless crate, you need to directly list it in `Cargo.toml` and enable the feature, i.e. add the line `heapless = { version = "0.7", features = ["serde"] }` to `Cargo.toml`. You can then `use heapless::Vec` directly. The serde-json-core crate does not need to support `heapless::Vec` directly – all that matters is that `heapless::Vec` implements the `Deserialize` trait, which it does once you enable the feature.

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted.

Comment: I summarized these comments in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `serde-json-core` crate can deserialize JSON arrays into any type that implements the `Deserialize` trait. If you want to avoid memory allocations, you need to pick a container that does not allocate.

If the size of the array is known in advance, you can simply use a fixed-sized array, i.e. `[T; N]`. This will return a deserialization error if the size of JSON array is not exactly `N`.

If the size of the JSON array is variable with a known upper limit, you can use one of various vector-like stack-allocated datastructures.  One such option is the [`heapless::Vec`](https://docs.rs/heapless/0.7.8/heapless/struct.Vec.html), which implements `Deserialize` if you enable the `serde` feature for `heapless`. In your `Cargo.yaml` file, you can do this like this:

```
heapless = { version = "0.7", features = ["serde"] }
```

If you use the same version of `heapless` that your version of `serde-json-core` depends on, it will only be included in your build once.